# What would you call a person who keeps track of money?

Tags: single-word-requests, money

The assumption is that the said person's full-time job is to keep records of in-flow and out-flow of cash or money.

Comment: This phrase has a negative connotation: "bean counter."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**accountant**
*noun*
a person concerned with the maintenance and audit of business accounts and the preparation of consultant reports in tax and finance.  Source: [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/accountant)

**bookkeeper**
*countable noun*
a person whose job is to keep an accurate record of the money that is spent and received by a business or other organization.  Source: [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bookkeeper)

Comment: Or **Treasurer**  - *an officer of a government, corporation, association, or the like, in charge of the receipt, care, and disbursement of money* [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/treasurer?s=t)

Comment: @Pete - Yeah, in some sort of club or social organization "treasurer" would almost certainly be used (at least in the US).  You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In colleges and some other organizations this is a [bursar](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bursar): *a person whose job is to manage the money of a school, college, or university*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be amusing, when talking about the member of the family who sits down to pay the bills once a month, you could say

*the chancellor (or secretary) of the exchequer*